# How to enter mathematical symbols in a msc diagram?

Tags: ieeetran, math-operators, unicode-math, msc

I am trying to enter the set notation symbol in the instance of a msc diagram,

but it whenever i do

the entire msc diagram disappears in the overleaf

I am using **IEEE Systems Journal** LaTeX Template

here's what i want to do;

[image: desired msc diagram material]

and here's a list of all my imports/packages;

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{msc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % this pkg allowed words inside msc diagrams to be bold !
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern,babel,adjustbox,booktabs,multirow}


\renewcommand\msckeyword{} 

\newlength{\minwidth}
\newcommand{\resizebox}[1]{
\setlength{\minwidth}{\widthof{
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
#1
\end{tabular}
}}
\parbox{\minwidth}{
#1
}
}

% \usepackage[numbers, square]{natbib}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}
```

and here's the code for the msc diagram

```
\begin{msc}{Sharing Authentication}
\setlength{\instwidth}{2.3cm}
\setlength{\actionwidth}{2.6cm}
\setlength{\instdist}{4.0cm}
\declinst{d1}{device1}{IoT1 NW\textsubscript{1}}
\begin{msc}
```

P.S : basically when i use \in , the entire msc diagram fails to render

Comment: do not show code as an image, make a small complete document that shows the problem and add to your question in  code block. Remove any packages not needed to show the problem

Comment: the symbol you show is `$a \in X$` which would make _a_  ∈ _X_ but is unrelated to any of the code you show in your image

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle, i'll show the code for both, please wait 5 min for the edits. i'll post another comment when it's done

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it's done ! please check the code

Comment: we still can not see what your issue is. as the code is just disconnected fragments. Make a small complete document preferbly starting `\documentclass{article}` and ending `\end{document}` that shows your problem. Say what output you expect and what error you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use math mode

```
\declinst{d1}{device1}{$\mathrm{IoT1}\in \mathrm{NW}_{1}$}
```

Before showing the full code, some considerations. First of all, never neglect error messages.

The instructions

- `\renewcommand{\msckeyword}{}`
- `\newcommand{\resizebox}{...}`

raise errors; the first command is not defined, the latter *is* defined and you should not change it.

Some of the package you load should be removed:

1. `pstricks`, unless you really need it.
2. `float` and `cite`; the former adds nothing really useful, the latter because IEEE has its own preferences for citation call-outs.
3. `lmodern` because it overrides `newtx` and chooses a font different from IEEE preferred one.
4. `babel`, since you don't seem to be using languages different from English.

In the code below I just keep uncommented the packages that are needed to produce the example and removed a couple, together with the wrong instructions. You can safely remove `\def\BibTeX{...}`. I've never understood why the IEEE templates insist in adding it.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{calc}
%\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{msc}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % this pkg allowed words inside msc diagrams to be bold !
%\usepackage{afterpage}
%\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{adjustbox,booktabs,multirow}


\begin{document}

\begin{msc}{Sharing Authentication}
\setlength{\instwidth}{2.3cm}
\setlength{\actionwidth}{2.6cm}
\setlength{\instdist}{4.0cm}
\declinst{d1}{device1}{$\mathrm{IoT}1\in NW_{1}$}
\end{msc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! you're a Godsend !